# How do we print self name of unix server?

Tags: shell, unix

My server name is **a1234.xyz.com** and i am logged in the server.
I have requirement of printing the server name within a shell script.

how to print the server name using UNIX command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `hostname` command:

```
hostname
```

Depending on how the system is configured, this might print either `a1234` or `a1234.xyz.com`, more likely just `a1234`.

Depending on what kind of system you're using, there might be an option to print the full hostname; `man hostname` for more information. (On Linux systems, `hostname -f`, `hostname --fqdn`, or `hostname --long` should work.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo -n `hostname`
```

Works on any BSD system...

Comment: Thanks @JimLewis for editing this to show the backticks

Comment: Why ``echo -n `hostname` `` rather than just `hostname`? The only difference is that `echo -n` doesn't print a trailing newline, and the question didn't say that was a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash you can...

- Use the `hostname` command:

  nunks@konata:~$ hostname
  konata
- Use the $HOSTNAME variable:

  nunks@konata:~$ echo $HOSTNAME
  konata
- Or assign either one to your own variable:

  nunks@konata:~$ myvar=$HOSTNAME
  nunks@konata:~$ echo $name
  konata

  nunks@konata:~$ myvar=$(hostname)
  nunks@konata:~$ echo $name
  konata

The last option above, assigning the result of the `hostname` command to your variable seems to be the more flexible one, since you can tailor it with any flags it supports, as described by @keith-thompson.